# Problem with deserialization of LocalDateTime in Junit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, jackson

I have problems `LocalDateTime` deserialization in `Junit` test. I have simple `REST API` which returns some `DTO` object. When I call my endpoint there is no problem with response - it is correct. Then I try to write unit test, obtain `MvcResult` and with use of `ObjectMapper` convert it to my `DTO` object. But I still receive:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.time.LocalDateTime` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (String)"{"name":"Test name","firstDate":[2019,3,11,18,34,43,52217600],"secondDate":[2019,3,11,19,34,43,54219000]}"; line: 1, column: 33] (through reference chain: com.mylocaldatetimeexample.MyDto["firstDate"])
```

I was trying with `@JsonFormat` and adding `compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.9.8'` to my `build.gradle` but I use `Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE` so it is involved in it. I do not have any idea how to fix it. My simple endpoint and unit test below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/myexample")
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<MyDto> findById(@PathVariable Long id) {

        MyDto myDto = new MyDto("Test name", LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(1));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(myDto);
    }
}
```

MyDto class

```
public class MyDto {

    private String name;
    private LocalDateTime firstDate;
    private LocalDateTime secondDate;

// constructors, getters, setters
}
```

Unit test

```
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void getMethod() throws Exception {
        MyController controller = new MyController();
        MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();

        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/myexample/1"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()).andReturn();

        String json = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        MyDto dto = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, MyDto.class);

        assertEquals("name", dto.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You create new `ObjectMapper` in test class:

```
MyDto dto = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, MyDto.class);
```

Try to inject `ObjectMapper` from `Spring` context or manually register module:

```
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

See also:

- [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime)